# How to find audio files that are completely silent

Tags: python

There is a set of audio in wav format. I heard that there are libraries in python that detect silence. Tell me how to find audio that is completely consisting of silence (well, or below some kind of sound threshold)

Comment: please read this before ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you know how to find numbers in a list, then you know how to detect silence (or samples with an amplitude below a certain threshold) in a `.wav` file. The format is very straight forward - it's just some meta-data (number of channels, samplerate, etc.) followed by the actual PCM (Pulse Code Modulated) samples. If there is one channel (Mono), all samples are contiguous. If there are two channels (Stereo), the samples from the left and right channels are interleaved. Each sample is really just a number that represents the amplitude at a certain point in time. Look into the `wave` module.

Answer (score 1):

you can use SciPy to create an array of the values in the audio file and then check the volume and process the file from there.

```
from scipy.io import wavfile
samplerate, data = wavfile.read('./output/audio.wav')
```

when you do this you get two variables out. One is the sample rate or speed of the audio and the other is the actual data in a NumPy array.

```
from scipy.io import wavfile
samplerate, data = wavfile.read('./output/audio.wav')
maxVolume = 0.5
isLoud = False
for i in data:
    if i > maxVolume:
        isLoud = True
        break
if isLoud:
   print("Loud")
```

This is a very simple way to get loud sounds and could have a better loudness detection system but I get the feeling you can handle that.

If you want to go advanced in 'loud detector', here is a good topic to look into:

- Fourier transform (kind of a requirement)

Comment: I check all the files in the loop `for f in wav_dir. glob ("*. wav"):` and at some point I get.

`WavFileWarning: Chunk (non-data) not understood, skipping it.` Can you tell me how I can catch this file?

Comment: use a 
try: 
    {your code}
except WavFileWarning:
    {your code for if it fails}

Comment: I've tried it. It doesn't work, it doesn't go into except

Comment: Try “except Error: print(Error)” just to see what happens